# Wavefunctions and Hamilton-Jacobi equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, differentiation, calculus

I was reading this paper, [Wavefunctions and Hamilton-Jacobi Equation](https://physicsgirl.com/11qmfromcmv3.pdf). The author started with the Hamiltonian formalism and then came up with a connection to the Schrodinger equation. There was a technical point in the calculation (equation 6) that I did not understand. Quoting from the paper:

> Acting twice on $e^{i \frac{S}{\hbar}}$ with $\hat p_j=\frac{\hbar}{i}\partial_{q_j}$ introduces corrections of order $\mathcal O (\hbar)$ to the value of $p^2_j \cdot e^{i \frac{S}{\hbar}}$: 
> $$\hat p_j^2 e^{i \frac{S}{\hbar}}=(\frac{\hbar}{i}\partial_{q_j})^2 e^{i \frac{S}{\hbar}} = [(\frac{\partial S}{\partial q_j})^2 + \frac{\hbar}{i} \frac{\partial^2S}{\partial q_j^2}]e^{i \frac{S}{\hbar}}.$$

What I do not understand is, how does acting twice on  $e^{i \frac{S}{\hbar}}$ with $\hat p_j=\frac{\hbar}{i}\partial_{q_j}$ introduces corrections of order $\mathcal O (\hbar)$ to the value of $p^2_j \cdot e^{i \frac{S}{\hbar}}$? That is, how do you get the last equality? Can someone please help me understand this?

Comment: Hi Peter Pan. Welcome to Phys.SE. Please don't repost a closed question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

Comment: Your link is not to a paper with the title you mention.

Comment: Sorry. Fixed the link now.

Comment: @Qmechanic Okay, I won't repost a question again. But my question was closed on the basis that it was homework-like question. Are you not supposed to ask a question about understanding how a step followed from the previous step in a calculation?

Comment: General tip: An edit of a closed question sends it to the review queue for a 2nd opinion.

Comment: ^^ right but the way your question is phrased, it just looks like you want someone to find the answer for you.  Moreover, as phrased, this question is of limited value to the community beyond your own interest.  The author is taking a derivative twice so what's *conceptually* hard about that, or do you simply have an issue with taking two derivatives?

Comment: You are absolutely right. I am sorry, it was an absolutely stupid question. It was the simplest differentiation but I carried it out wrongly and thought that I was missing something.

Comment: @PeterPan it was not necessarily a stupid question: when you look at it wrong you look at it wrong.  This is why carefully thinking about the conceptual aspect of a question is important in asking well-received questions.  FYI I don’t think this derivation is “new”, or at least I’m pretty sure I saw something similar elsewhere.

Comment: Yeah, it's not quite "new" perhaps. I also think I saw something similar while reading up on the path integral formalism of quantum mechanics somewhere.